# WebPRNT Star TSP - google chrome flag "Block insecure private network requests" not work

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, printing

I would like to use webPRNT with TSP654II but looks like chrome newer version block this type of communication... I found a flag switch it to disable but nothing happend.

Google Chrome version: 100.0.4896.60

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://192.168.0.100/StarWebPRNT/SendMessage' from origin 
'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't 
pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Private-Network' header was present in the 
preflight response for this private network request targeting the `private` address space.
```

any idea how to figureout this?

Comment: How do you use Chrome for printing? I have been trying to figure it out since clouprint is too limiting but I had no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

chrome://flags/#block-insecure-private-network-requests

open above link in browser and Just disable this flag in chrome

Comment: wont worked withchrome version v94-100, now loks working again. (thank you it was a good reminder as well and now able to use again this feature)